# How to get energy gap change at specific high symmetry points during ab initio molecular simulations？

Tags: vasp, molecular-dynamics, electronic-structure

I want to check the energy gap change during finite temperature *ab initio* molecular simulations. The results may look like this picture:
[image]

How can set aimd simulation to get this result in VASP?

Comment: I think that you need to calculate the bands for each time step, extract the gap, and then plot a graph like that.